# C# Autofac. Parameters for dependency at resolution time

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm using `Autofac` as `IoC container` and I want to resolve with parameters at resolution time.
But I want to pass arguments to a dependency of resolution tree not to the class that I call on `Resolve` method.

Supose having this scenario with two classes

```
public interface IService(){ }

public class Service : IService{
    public Service(ILogger logger){ }
}


public interface Logger : ILogger{ }

public class Logger : ILogger{
    public Logger (LoggerConfig options){ }
}
```

And this is the Container creation following `Autofac` documentation

```
public static IContainer CreateContainer(){
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>();
    builder.Register<Logger>((c, p) => new Logger(p.AsTyped<LoggerConfig>())).As<ILogger>();
    return builder.Build();
}
```

I have discovered that if I want to resolve with parameters the `ILogger` I have to resolve `ILogger` first instead of resolve `IService` which is the class that I want to resolve.

If I try to resolve like this it doesn't work

```
var container = CreateContainer();
container.Resolve<IService>(new TypedParameter(typeof(LoggerConfig), new LoggerConfig()));
```

I have to resolve first ILogger like this

```
var container = CreateContainer();
container.Resolve<ILogger>(new TypedParameter(typeof(LoggerConfig), new LoggerConfig()));
container.Resolve<IService>();
```

So the question is. How can I pass arguments at resolution time to a dependency of the class that I want to resolve?

Comment: [This is an FAQ](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/injecting-global-parameters.html) and touches on [a common example.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html)